# How to print multiple object from table def __str__(self):return self.title

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I created a article models below
**models.py**

```
class Article(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    custom_id = models.UUIDField(blank=False,null=False, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField("created on", auto_now_add=True)
    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

for print the title object I Used below lines

```
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

But I want to print the title object with user object.How will do? For Example

```
Title Name
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You format it with the username (or some other field) with:

```
def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.title} {self.user.username}'
```

or you can use the `str(…)` implementation of the user with:

```
def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.title} {self.user}'
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).